# Set gradient on UIView partially, half color is gradient and half is single color

Tags: iphone, swift, ios9

Trying to show the progress bar made it custom, took an UIView set it frame to percent of progress. Say 20% of frame width and made gradient but remaining 80% should be white color and text on it defining percentage.

Problems facing is not able to display text set UILabel instead of UIView but text not displaying. Please guide.
Below is what i have tried.

```
let view: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, self.scrollMainView.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width/5, 50))
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = view.bounds
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    let color0 = UIColor(red:71.0/255, green:198.0/255, blue:134.0/255, alpha:1.0).CGColor
    let color1 = UIColor(red:25.0/255, green:190.0/255, blue: 205.0/255, alpha:1.0).CGColor
   // let color2 = UIColor(red:0.0/255, green:0.0/255, blue: 0.0/255, alpha:1.0).CGColor

    gradient.colors = [color1, color0]
    view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
    self.scrollMainView.addSubview(view)

    view.text = "20%"
    view.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer to why you can't see the text.

Forget for one second layers and think about subviews. What should happen if you add a subview to a UILabel? It will be on top of the label's content, of course.

So, the same applies to layers. The UILabel draws its text on its main layer, and any sublayer you add to the main layer is on top of it.

My suggestion is to use a UIView with a CAGradientLayer sublayer and a UILabel subview.

Or even better, subclass a UIView in order to use a CAGradientLayer as backing layer (through `class func layerClass() -> AnyClass` method) and just add UILabel as subview.

Here is an example:

```
class CustomView : UIView {
    lazy var label : UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel(frame: self.bounds)
        l.text = "20%"
        l.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        l.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return l
    }()

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        let color0 = UIColor(red:71.0/255, green:198.0/255, blue:134.0/255, alpha:1.0).CGColor
        let color1 = UIColor(red:25.0/255, green:190.0/255, blue: 205.0/255, alpha:1.0).CGColor

        gradient.colors = [color1, color0]

        label.frame = bounds
        label.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand your problem from your question exactly but I will answer based on question title only. To get half color gradient and half single color you have to use three colors gradient and set their locations accordingly :

```
gradient.colors = [color1,color1, color0]
gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
```

This way you will draw a gradient from color1 to color1 (which in fact is single color) and fill 50% of frame's area with it and a gradient from color1 to color0 that will fill other half of the frame.